# how to select parent of <script> element

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="scriptparent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $( /* select above <div> from <script> ... without id and div property */ )
    </script>
</div>
```

from the code I have a `<script>` block inside `<div>` block. I'd like to select `<div>` from `<script>` without id, class, name selectors. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the code is as you've shown it and so it's running **right away**, as the DOM is being built, you may be able to do something with `document.body.lastChild`.

So the short answer to you question is:

```
var div = $(document.body.lastChild).closest('div');
```

I'm being a bit paranoid there, in my tests (on Chrome), `document.body.lastChild` **is** the `div`, but by using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) I deal with the possibility it could be `script` on some engines.

The long answer is an example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/azogob/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/azogob/2/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Last Element ID</title>
  <script>
    function setUpParentDiv() {
      var div = $(document.body.lastChild).closest('div');
      switch (div.attr("id")) {
        case "div1":
          div.css("color", "blue");
          break;
        case "div2":
          div.css("color", "green");
          break;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    I'm div1
    <script>
      setUpParentDiv();
    </script>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    I'm div2
    <script>
      setUpParentDiv();
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is amazing but how can i select node with jquery?

Comment: @thkang: Sorry, I'd only half-read the jQuery bit. I've updated the example to make it more jQuery-focussed, and put the "short answer" at the beginning.

Comment: I believe `body.lastChild` will never return a `script` element in this case as the script elements are not direct children of the body element.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I'm not following you, the live links above *do* work. Note that the OP didn't want the script element, he/she wanted the `div`, which *is* a direct child of `body`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it works. I just commented because you mentioned being paranoid about `body.lastChild` being the `script` element in some engines, which I doubt that would ever happen seeing as these `script` elements are not directly children of the `body`. In this case, `body.lastChild` is unlikely to return the script element unless the implementation is highly defective. `=]`

Answer (score 14):

```
 <div id="scriptparent">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var scriptTag = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
            var parentTag = scriptTag.parentNode;
            alert(parentTag.id);
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 11):

If your script tags are not defered (all loaded synchronously) then this will work:

```
<div id="scriptparent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1],
            parent = thisScript.parentNode; // points to div#scriptparent
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

The script tag supports all HTML global attributes, which includes `id`.  Add an `id` to your script tag, which an be used as a hook to select the parent.

```
<div id="scriptparent">
<script id="myScript" type="text/javascript">
   alert($("#myScript").parent().attr("id"));
</script>
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5fTyK/

Comment: what about there are more than one instances of the above code? `$("#myScript")` won't select the closest one

Comment: and more than once instances shouldn't have same `id` and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions have worked for me, my script in inserted by angular as a part of CMS and in repeatable block.

"some_div" class name should be sort of unique for this sort of insertions.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some_div" style="display: none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function(){
  var local_id = 'Div_' + Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);
  $('.some_div').not( ".processed" ).attr({id: local_id})
  var alert_div = $('#' + local_id);
  
  alert_div.show().html('nearby div')
  alert_div.addClass('processed');
 }, 20)
</script>
```