# adding element to the code parent

Tags: javascript, html

so i want to write a js code to create a image tag  .... something like this

```
var oImg=document.createElement("img");
oImg.setAttribute('src', 'www.site.com/banner/a.gif');
oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');
document.body.appendChild(oImg);
```

so here is the problem ... right now it just appends the image to the body 
but i want it to show up exactly where i put this code ... for example if i put it in the sidebar i want that image to show up in the side bar

and i dont want to add any extra html tag to the page just this js code

is that possible ?

Comment: can you put an id on the script tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to select parent of <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909325/how-to-select-parent-of-script-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the current script tag by ID

```
<script id='image_replace'>
    var oImg=document.createElement("img");
    oImg.setAttribute('src', 'http://placehold.it/350x150');
    oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');
    var this_script = document.getElementById('image_replace');
    this_script.parentElement.replaceChild(oImg,this_script);
</script>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/e2Lqh9ef/

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote append the img in the body because it says: "document.BODY.appendChild(yourElementToAppend)". Of course it will append elements to the the body.

In order to answer your question, your reasoning is not correct. 
The best way to solve your problem is giving an id (or a class) to the sidebar (or to the element you need to appen a child) while in the .js you can easily use jQuery and write the same code you put in the question except the last row, which should be substitute with:
$(".nameIdYouWroteInTheSidebar").appendChild(oImg);

Hope this can be useful :)